# How reliable is DMA to GPIO on STM32 MCUs?

Tags: timer, stm32, gpio, dma, stm32f4

ST has some application notes that talk about emulating a parallel bus using DMA to GPIO. I appreciate that, but it doesn't answer important questions. I am looking through the reference manual, and I can't seem to find clarify the things that I am concerned about.

I am most concerned about the jitter. The reference manual repeatedly states, that when DMA is triggered (e.g., by a timer), the DMA controller will read the memory and transfer the value to the peripheral. That might be fine with peripherals that have their own FIFO. There, when space is available in the FIFO, DMA is triggered and fills the FIFO. That will probably happen before the FIFO runs empty.

But with GPIO, if the DMA channels doesn't have a FIFO itself, the data will not be ready when the timer triggers and it needs to be fetched from SRAM. So between the timer triggering and between the value actually arriving in the GPIO output register, some time may pass. This might be measurable when looking at the clock output by the timer and the GPIO pins. The DMA controller has to compete for access to the SRAM with the running program, so certain activities by the program may increase the jitter.

Maybe that is a colossal oversight on my part, but ST's reference manual doesn't seem mention a FIFO as part of the DMA. If that is the case, that would result in jitter which may impact performance at higher frequencies.

I need to toggle 3 to 4 pins synchronously to a clock from 100kHz to 1MHz. I am considering DMA to GPIO and also abusing a QuadSPI controller. I am currently testing on a STM32L4 but I'm also considering STM32F4 or even F1.

Comment: Do you know which application note this is? I had a parallel bus at 1 MHz implemented as a test on STM32H743, then built a circuit around a STM32F407 and now I can't get it to work in the same way (DMA doesn't trigger on the timer and/or DMA transfer error and/or other problems).

Comment: I believe I was referring to AN4666:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00169730-parallel-synchronous-transmission-using-gpio-and-dma-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Answer (score 1):

DMA to/from GPIOit is just memory-to-memory transfer. Many STM32 uCs have built in DMA FIFOs - but they will have not use here.

The core has always priority over the DMA so if it can be the issue (very unlikely) place the core accesible data (this data which uC will access when DMA is active in the separate memory area - for example CCM (if your uC has one)

Answering the question
memory to/FROM GPIO is very reliable - I personally did not have any problems with it.

Comment: Which uCs have you been using?

Comment: I use them in my work. Plenty models L4 L0 F3 F4 F7 H7 G4 & G0

Comment: AFAIK, DMA interfaces differ between those STM32 lines: The more powerful have a FIFO while the slower (check L0 or F3, for instance...) don't have a FIFO IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

If your clock can be anything between 100 kHz and 1 MHz, I guess you're not worried about jitter in the clock itself, only jitter in the data versus the clock. If your clock need not be continuous, a novel idea then is to do some preprocessing of the data to include the clock signal as *part of the GPIO data*. Then you could trigger the DMA at regular intervals using a timer, and you'll get the data frequency on the bus at half that rate with perfect alignment between clock and data.

So if you you want to send the four-bit data `5 6 B D` with data valid on the positive clock edge, prepare the DMA buffer as so: `05 15 06 16 0B 1B 0D 1D` and connect the GPIO pin 4 as the clock. Leave a final byte in the buffer to reset the clock/bus to idle state, if you need.

You can of course extend the idea and incorporate control signals such as chip selects and tri-state signals for external buffers, if needed.

Also take note that not all DMA blocks may have access to the AHB bus which is holding the GPIO registers. For example on STM32F40x, only DMA2 can be used (this is what got me, until I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46619315/6552613).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully explored this space yet, but, by disabling interrupts and polling for interrupt flags in my main loop, it's made the jitter on my GPIO DMA basically disappear!  Granted it might just be the set of interrupts have enabled, but everything down to the systick timer was killing me.  By polling the interrupts in the main loop it seems to have fixed my issue.

Note that this is on an STM32F042, and I never exceed 6 MHz for my period. When I try to, i.e. try to go to 8 MHz sampling out, everything falls apart. YMMV